# Calling python script on PATH

Tags: python, path, scripting

I have added a python script to my PATH variable in linux, but when I called it does not seem to execute.

**Steps I've tried:**

I have checked that it is pointing to the right file with which.

I have added a bash script in the same directory as the python file, it worked fine.

I have tried to print to terminal as well as generate a file, neither worked.

I have successfully run the script by calling it directly from within the directory.

I am using the BASH shell if that helps, but I am stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: Ho are you calling the script, both in the directory and when you are outside?

Comment: Without further information no one will be able to give you an exact answer. How exactly are you trying to execute the script? Does the file start with a Python shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`)? Does the file have execute permissions (`chmod a+x $file`)?

Comment: If I call it just by name, it doesn't work regardless of inside or out, but if I call it with the leading ./, it does if I'm in the directory

Comment: command lines you used ? what happens when you call `python` ? same question for `python <yourscript.py`> ?

Comment: The first line is #!/usr/bin/env python3, it does have execute permissions (just to test, used chmod 777), and will run if I use python3 in that directory no matter what the name is, but will only run without the explicit python3 if it ends with .py